# Dash across letter (letter đ)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

How can I put a dash across the letter d? Not through the middle but only through the top vertical line bit. It's like the `\hbar` used in physics but with a d.

Comment: Please always see [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol. Usually questions like this get closed as duplicate, but I don't think it makes sense doing it now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
\dj
```

[image: d with dash]

For this you need to load the `fontenc` package

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

When looking for a symbol, remember using [Detextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which is a beautiful tool, created just for this purpose, or check the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).