# Spacing issue with defined character

Tags: spacing, kerning

I needed a character that looks like a d with a bar through it, so I found this snippet of code.

```
\newcommand{\dbar}{{\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}
```

This creates the right character, but it doesn't have normal spacing for a math symbol, so I end up with something like the picture below, where I've included a regular $\hat{d}$ for comparison to what it should look like. Any advice on how to fix this?

[image: dbar]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/dash-across-letter-letter-%C4%91 and a better one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203508/d-with-a-little-line-through-the-top-of-it

Comment: I moved my answer to the question this has been marked a duplicate of.